# Como modificar estilos a un editor de texto CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, html, css

estoy usando un editor para el textarea, pero no le puedo modificar los estilos. intente desde la hoja de estilos e incluso con estilos en linea pero no funciona.

```
<textarea cols="30" rows="15" id="cargar-cuerpo" class="cuerpo"></textarea>


<script> ClassicEditor
            .create(document.querySelector('#cargar-cuerpo'))
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            }
            );
    </script>
```

Comment: qué editor es? Posiblemente cargue sus propios estilos...

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. El editor es CKEditor

Comment: CKEditor tiene opciones para [configurar estilos](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/features/styles.html). Solo por no dejar lugar a duda, ¿es el editor de Wordpress?

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. El editor es de HTML

Comment: lo que quiero hacer unicamente es cambiarle el height. Por lo que vi la manera de hacerlo seria colocando esto CKEDITOR.config.height = '300px'; Lo que no se es en que parte